# What Hogwarts students are twins?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

We know that the Weasley twins and the Patil twins go to Hogwarts. But are there other sets of twins that are depicted?

In particular, what are the names of the twin girls wearing green dresses in the party that Professor Slughorn held in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*?

Comment: This seems pretty broad, but answerable. I might have a stab at it

Comment: Topic is broad but I think as long as answers stick to canon sources there should be some info here (particularly about the twins in the green dresses). One thing I would ask for though is whether you're asking about the movies or the books (were the twins in both?).

Comment: The twins at the slug club party were Flora and Hestia Carrow; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Flora_Carrow

Comment: I've edited to reflect what I think you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 9):

### Film Twins.

You've already mentioned **Fred and George Weasley**

[image]

And **Parvati and Padma Patil**

[image]

The female twins at the Slug Club party are [**Hestia and Flora Carrow**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Flora_Carrow)

[image]
[image]

---

### Others (canon)

Others mentioned in canon include

- Luna's children; [**Lorcan and Lysander Scamander**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lorcan) (via [A Year in the Life](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_6SVzaxaHvV8/R3hpB0JG45I/AAAAAAAABaQ/x3fY5zlOZ3w/s1600-h/Family+Tree.jpg) and [Pottermore](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/DUMBLEDORE%27S_ARMY_REUNITES_AT_QUIDDITCH_WORLD_CUP_FINAL))
- [**Helixa and Syna Hyslop**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Helixa_Hyslop) (via Wonderbook: Book of Spells)
- [**Martha and Rionach Stewart**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Martha_Steward_II) (via Pottermore)
- [**The Vibes Twins**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Vibes_Twins) (via The Making of Harry Potter)

There are also two (male) twins seen in Deathly Hallows, Part II, tentatively (and probably erroneously) identified by the wiki as Luna's sons.

[image]

Comment: I thought Lorcan and Lysander are from the A Year in the Life documentary.

Comment: But mentioned on Pottermore (albeit indirectly); "*Luna has been sweeping around the VIP section in robes composed of the flags of all sixteen qualifying countries. **Her twin sons** are ‘at home with grandpa'.*"

Comment: I guess, but I wouldn't call that their origin.

Comment: @ibid - Happy now?

Comment: I would be even happier if you linked stuff to primary sources, but yes.

Comment: Hestia and Flora Carrow look like a barrel of laughs.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - They're smiling on the inside, I'm sure

Comment: @TheDarkLord pot kettle black much? :p